# onMessageReceived() is called from FCM but not from app Server

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

recently I'm learning push notification. I've configured with FCM while testing from the FCM `onMessageReceived()` method is called. But I can't receive any push notification from the App server. I've checked the device_token sent to the server it was the same as I tested in FCM.

```
 @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(@NonNull RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);

        Log.d("Task*******************",remoteMessage.getData().toString());
}
```

In MainActivity.java

```
FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId().addOnCompleteListener(this);
```

I Can't even find out what was my mistake. Should I call it manually if so then how?

If you could help me plz.

Comment: Did you include google-services.json file in Android studio? it is the mistake we do mostly @Quote Spk

Comment: yes i've included inside app directory :-\

Comment: Are you testing it from a firebase test message or any other backend?

Comment: Are you calling firebase token using onNewToken() method ?

Comment: i'm testing from both firebase test message and app server. From FCM notification is received by calling onMessageReceived() but how to call onMessageReceived() method when notification from App server

Comment: maybe the issue is when you are sending the firebase token to the server or firebase test message. Are you getting token in onNewToken() method or the other method? @Quote Spk

Comment: no i didn't use onNewToken(), i send token to the server using this code        FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<InstanceIdResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<InstanceIdResult> task) {
                String token = task.getResult().getToken();
            }
        });

Comment: Try sending from onNewToken() because firebase sends the token when the user installs the app and i have done this in many apps using onNewToken() and put that token in shared preference to store it and use it for other features when it has to be used.

Comment: okay . I'll try, Thanks a lot

Comment: You're welcome. Let me know if that works.

Comment: I've stored the token and send to the server again i checked with fcm  it worked perfectly but not in App Server. if it works in fcm it should also work with app server, ami i right? if so why can't i receive ?

Comment: App server should store that fcm token in their database with your specific login id. Maybe check the server if it is taking the fcm token correctly or not. Try to print the fcm token and verify it with the server.

Comment: ok sure. is there any other possibilities?

Comment: just use logcat to print the token and verify with backend developer whether they are getting the update token or not.

Comment: Okay sure, Thank for your time to taught me :-D

Comment: you are welcome. Its the most important part to receive push notifications so. Just making sure where you might gone wrong.